# Can't enable Gitlab notification email for failed pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to get email notification for failed pipeline builds.

I tried to configure my GitLab settings as following: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/notifications.html

But in my settings, I see the following: [image]

There is no check box for Failed/Successful pipeline.
For the project I set it to 'Watch:' receive notifications from projects or groups user is a member of.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your GitLab version? Newest version has both checkboxes.

Comment: I'd watch this for ideal fix, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25524

Comment: you might be able to hack it together with an on_failure trigger (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#when) and send an email through means other than gitlab at that step

Answer (score 4):

Even if the question is old, the solution is the Gitlab Integration "Pipeline emails" (suggested by this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472631/notify-all-group-members-of-failed-pipelines-in-gitlab)).

In short, in your project, go to `Project -> Settings -> Integrations -> Pipelines emails` and set the list of emails to notify.

Comment: Can we send the `artifacts` using this approach via Email.Yet now i have set the email address, but not getting any mail now.Could you please help me on it

Answer (score 1):

The link to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/notifications.html is no more active.

I found a blog post from 2020 on https://about.gitlab.com/blog/, explaining how to do.
Read it there : **https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/06/17/notification-on-pipeline-succeeds/**

In short, you have checkboxes for *custom notification events* like :

- failed pipeline
- fixed pipeline
- successful pipeline
- etc.

To access it, like said in the blog post,

1. Go to the Project overview page for the project.
2. Click the "bell"  (Notification setting) button and select Custom.

And before all, check your global notification email at : https://gitlab.com/-/profile/notifications