# Notify all group members of failed pipelines in GitLab

Tags: notifications, gitlab, pipeline

The goal is to have everyone get a notification for every failed pipeline (at their discretion). Currently, any of us can run a pipeline on this project branch, and the creator of the pipeline gets an email, no one else does. I have tried setting the notification level to `watch` and `custom (with failed pipelines checked)` at project, group and global levels without success. The help page regarding [notifications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/notifications.html) says the failed pipeline checkbox for custom notification levels notifies the author of the pipeline (which is the behavior I am experiencing). Is there any way to allow multiple people to get notified of a failed pipeline?

- Using Gitlab CE v10.0
- Have Group (security::internal)
- Group has Project (security::internal)
- Project has scheduled pipleine (runs nighly)
- Pipeline runs integration tests (purposely failing)
- Schedule created by me (schedules have to have an owner)
- When the automated pipeline runs and fails, I get an email (good)
- No one else gets email (bad)

Comment: Have a look at "Project -> Settings -> Integrations -> Pipelines emails"

Comment: @SaschaFrinken Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I'll gladly accept your answer if you move this to an answer!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have a look at following Integration:

`Project -> Settings -> Integrations -> Pipelines emails`

[image]

Comment: Is there any option to add only committer, dynamically??

Comment: @Fakhrul Hasan I think this can't be done with the integration. But You could use a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#pipeline-events)

Comment: is there such an option for choosing specific scheduled pipelines?

Comment: I am not receiving any emails even though I have added comma-separated emails and even try a single email address under the recipients' section. Is it working for you?

Comment: @Wolfson - I'm pretty sure not. See e.g. this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/220059